# IAR Embedded Workbench

Tags: c, embedded, iar

I am trying to open an already created project in IAR (I created it on another computer) and want to open the project file in my own computer. When trying to open it, it says: The project (name of the project with the locations) could not be opened.

Is there a way to be able to open it? I have seen some people do that but when I try it does not work.

I have tried to open the file and it does not work

Comment: Did you use `File -> Open Workspace` or `File -> Open file`? Are both installations of IAR EW same version?

Comment: Also, did you open correct file type (`.eww`)?

Comment: yes I did, it says that the file is set to Read only

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add more details about your project. Show the directory structure and the files you have. You could use `tree -f` in the top level directory of your project. Regarding the error message about a read-only file: Add this information to your question and explain how you got the project to your computer.

Comment: This question you should ask IAR support as it is an expensive commercial product. I do not think that SO is the right place to ask.

Answer (score 1):

IAR projects are very sensitive to the IDE version in which they are created.

If not using the same IDE version:

- A newer IDE version will offer to upgrade an existing "**project.ewp**" and automatically create a "**Backup of project.ewp**", which might be unnecessary if the project is under version control.
- An earlier IDE version will refuse to open a project last saved on a newer IDE version. The EWP format is tightly tied to the IDE and, it is not backward compatible.

In the worst case the project file is a XML file which you can open and try to extract some human-readable information from there, such as the last version in which the file was saved. However a significant part of the information is encoded to the IDE inner workings and, as far as I know, there is no open specification about what such cryptic options might actually mean.